# Перетаскивание и изменение размера QLabel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, drag-n-drop, qlabel

Как реализовать перетаскивание и дать возможность изменять размер виджета `QLabel`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Предыдущие ваши вопросы решены?

Comment: Да, я забыл пометить, сори

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста пример с QLabel и уточните куда вы хотите ее перетащить.

Comment: Добавил, лейбл перетащить и разместить в GraphicsView и получить координаты расположения лейбла относительно отображаемого документа в GV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант (**Drag-and-Drop QLabel**):

```
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *                           
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 


class DraggableLabelImage(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, image, parent ):
        super(QLabel,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setPixmap(QPixmap(image).scaled(100, 100))    
        self.show()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drag_start_position = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not (event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton):
            return
        if (event.pos() - self.drag_start_position).manhattanLength() < QApplication.startDragDistance():
            return
        drag = QDrag(self)
        mimedata = QMimeData()
        mimedata.setText(self.text())
        mimedata.setImageData(self.pixmap().toImage())

        drag.setMimeData(mimedata)
        pixmap = QPixmap(self.size())
        painter = QPainter(pixmap)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self.grab())
        painter.end()
        drag.setPixmap(pixmap)
        drag.setHotSpot(event.pos())
        drag.exec_(Qt.CopyAction | Qt.MoveAction)


class DraggableLabel(QLabel):
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drag_start_position = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not (event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton):
            return
        if (event.pos() - self.drag_start_position).manhattanLength() < QApplication.startDragDistance():
            return
        drag = QDrag(self)
        mimedata = QMimeData()
        mimedata.setText(self.text())
        drag.setMimeData(mimedata)

        pixmap = QPixmap(self.size())
        painter = QPainter(pixmap)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self.grab())
        painter.end()

        drag.setPixmap(pixmap)
        drag.setHotSpot(event.pos())
        drag.exec_(Qt.CopyAction | Qt.MoveAction)


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        label_to_drag   = DraggableLabel("Это QLabel можно перетащить.", self) 
        labelImageDrag = DraggableLabelImage("D:/_Qt/img/head.jpg", self) 
        labelImageDrag.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(label_to_drag)
        layout.addWidget(labelImageDrag)


class GraphicsProxyWidget(QGraphicsProxyWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)  
        self.label  = DropLabel(" Переместите сюда QLabel.text() \n или QLabel.QPixmap(image)") 
        self.setWidget(self.label)   

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        event.acceptProposedAction()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        return self.widget().dropEvent(event)        

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        event.acceptProposedAction()    


class DropLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DropLabel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resize(250,250) 
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        event.acceptProposedAction()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():       
            self.setPixmap(QPixmap(event.mimeData().urls()[0].toLocalFile()).scaled(250, 250))  
            event.acceptProposedAction()  
        elif event.mimeData().hasImage():
            self.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage( QImage(event.mimeData().imageData())) ) 
            event.acceptProposedAction()  
        elif event.mimeData().hasText():     
            text = event.mimeData().text()
            self.setText(text)
            event.acceptProposedAction()       


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.widget = Widget()

        scene = QGraphicsScene(-20, -20, 290, 290, self)

        self.view = QGraphicsView(scene)
        self.view.setBackgroundBrush(QColor(28, 31, 34))

        proxy = GraphicsProxyWidget() 
        scene.addItem(proxy)

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.widget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.view)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]